# How to addClass if autocomplete input is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to add a class if autocomplete input is empty? There's a function which autocompletes the address when putting the post code. If for example `address_1` is empty, it adds the class `form-control`, else it adds the class `sem-bordas`.

I tried:

```
$('#input-address-1').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).next().removeClass("form-control");
    } else {
        $(this).next().addClass("sem-bordas");
    }
});
```

But without success.

Thats all the function

```
$(function(){              
  $('input[name="postcode"]').blur(function(){
    var cep = $.trim($('input[name="postcode"]').val().replace('-', ''));


    //$.getScript ("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep="+cep, function(){

     $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados){
      if(!("erro" in dados)){

        $('input[name="address_1"]').val(dados.logradouro);
        $('input[name="address_1"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');
        $('input[name="address_2"]').val(dados.bairro);
        $('input[name="address_2"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');
        $('input[name="city"]').val(unescape(dados.localidade));
        $('input[name="city"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');                

        $('select[name="zone_id"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');
        $('select[name="country_id"]').find('option[value="30"]').attr('selected', true);

        $.post('index.php?route=account/register/estado_autocompletar&estado=' + unescape(dados.uf), function(zone_id){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=account/register/country&country_id=30',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {

              $('select[name=\'country_id\']').after(' <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');

            },
            complete: function() {
              $('.fa-spin').remove();
            },      
            success: function(json) {
              if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
                $('#postcode-required').parent().parent().addClass('required');                        
              } else {
                $('#postcode-required').parent().parent().removeClass('required');
              }

              var html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

              if (json['zone'] != '') {
                for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                  html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';

                  if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == zone_id) {
                    html += ' selected="selected"';
                  }

                  html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
                }
              } else {
                html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';

              }

              $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having with this code?

Comment: If textbox is still empty after autocomplete is “closed”, the onchange is not fired.. Try using another event..

Comment: It is difficult to help you accurately on this question because some of the things you mention are not present in your question. Do you mean browser autocomplete? jQuery ui autocomplete or some other script? Where is this so called function? When do you want to do the check? on change of the input field? please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

After

```
 success: function(json) {
                  if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
                    $('#postcode-required').parent().parent().addClass('required');                        
                  } else {
                    $('#postcode-required').parent().parent().removeClass('required');
                  }
```

Put this code

```
 if($.trim($('#input-address-1').val()) == ''){
                    $('#input-address-1').addClass('form-control');
                  }else {
                    $('#input-address-1').removeClass('form-control');
                    $('#input-address-1').addClass('sem-bordas');
                  }
```

Thanks everyone for helping. I think thats the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('input','#input-address-1', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).next().addClass("sem-bordas");
    } else {
        $(this).next().removeClass("sem-bordas");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain, thats all my function to verify if the address exist or not

```
   $(function(){              
      $('input[name="postcode"]').blur(function(){
        var cep = $.trim($('input[name="postcode"]').val().replace('-', ''));


        //$.getScript ("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep="+cep, function(){

         $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados){
          if(!("erro" in dados)){

            $('input[name="address_1"]').val(dados.logradouro);
            $('input[name="address_1"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');
            $('input[name="address_2"]').val(dados.bairro);
            $('input[name="address_2"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');
            $('input[name="city"]').val(unescape(dados.localidade));
            $('input[name="city"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');                

            $('select[name="zone_id"]').parent().parent().fadeIn('slow');
            $('select[name="country_id"]').find('option[value="30"]').attr('selected', true);

            $.post('index.php?route=account/register/estado_autocompletar&estado=' + unescape(dados.uf), function(zone_id){
              $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=account/register/country&country_id=30',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {

                  $('select[name=\'country_id\']').after(' <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');

                },
                complete: function() {
                  $('.fa-spin').remove();
                },      
                success: function(json) {
                  if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
                    $('#postcode-required').parent().parent().addClass('required');                        
                  } else {
                    $('#postcode-required').parent().parent().removeClass('required');
                  }

                  var html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

                  if (json['zone'] != '') {
                    for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                      html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';

                      if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == zone_id) {
                        html += ' selected="selected"';
                      }

                      html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
                    }
                  } else {
                    html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';

                  }

                  $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html);
                }
              });
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Soon after putting the postcode and an address was not found, I would like to add a class to the fields that were not filled. The goal is to highlight fields that have not been filled